# How do i calculate average rate from a table?

Tags: r

Compute a table but with rates computed over 1999-2001. Keep only rows from 1999-2001 where players have 100 or more plate appearances, calculate each player's single rate and BB rate per season, then calculate the average single rate (mean_singles) and average BB rate (mean_bb) per player over those three seasons.

How many players had a single rate mean_singles of greater than 0.2 per plate appearance over 1999-2001?

```
library(tidyverse) 
library(Lahman)  

bat_02 <- Batting %>% filter(yearID %in% c("1999","2000","2001")) %>%
    mutate(pa = AB + BB, singles = (H - X2B - X3B - HR)/pa, bb = BB/pa) %>%
    filter(pa >= 100) %>%
    select(playerID, singles, bb)
        
bat_02 <- bat_02 %>% filter(singles > .2)
nrow(bat_02)
```

I have filtered the tables so it contain players with 100 or more plates appearance in year 1999-2001. I filtered the singles row with the condition: singles is more than 0.2. The following code gave me an output of 133, which is not correct. Is there any mistake in my code?

Comment: Your data has to be reproducible ([MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)). It's not acceptable to just say *"the dataset is taken from Lahman package"*, you need to edit the code with all the commands that are necessary to load that dataset (and/or give the URL to the dataset, if it's publicly downloadable). Also obviously show the output. because *"it give me an answer of 133"* tells us nothing, without being able to reproduce.

Comment: If 133 is not correct, what is?

Comment: I have edited my code.

Comment: @Nuclear03020704 i dont know, i suspect that my code only filtered the single per pa, but i cant figured out how do i calculate the average single rate.

Answer (score 3):

This is my take on the question.

```
library(Lahman)
library(dplyr)

str(Batting)

Batting %>% 
  #Compute a table but with rates computed over 1999-2001.
  filter(yearID %in% c("1999","2000","2001")) %>%

  #Keep only rows from 1999-2001 where players have 100 or more plate appearances
  mutate(pa = AB + BB) %>%
  filter(pa >= 100) %>%

  #calculate each player's single rate and BB rate per season
  group_by(playerID, yearID) %>%
  summarise(singles = (H - X2B - X3B - HR)/pa, bb = BB/pa) %>%

  #then calculate the average single rate (mean_singles) and average BB rate (mean_bb) per player over those three seasons.
  group_by(yearID) %>%
  summarise(mean_single=mean(singles), mean_bb=mean(bb))

# A tibble: 3 x 3
  yearID mean_single mean_bb
   <int>       <dbl>   <dbl>
1   1999       0.137  0.0780
2   2000       0.140  0.0765
3   2001       0.132  0.0634
```

---

Or perhaps the question wanted just the overall rates:

```
  #then calculate the average single rate (mean_singles) and average BB rate (mean_bb) per player over those three seasons.
  ungroup() %>%
  summarise(mean_single=mean(singles, na.rm=TRUE), mean_bb=mean(bb, na.rm=TRUE))
# A tibble: 1 x 2
  mean_single mean_bb
        <dbl>   <dbl>
1       0.136  0.0726
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. But, the average rate in your code is for the entire year right? I need the average rate per player over those three season (1999-2001). Would changing the group_by(yearID) into group_by(player_ID) will solve the problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The question is vague. We both interpret it differently. "Over those 3 seasons" can mean for each one, which is what I've done, or it can mean the overall. If you want just one single average, then replace the final `group_by` with `ungroup()`

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code that properly computes the required averages:

```
library(Lahman)

# Compute required averages for years 1999-2001
averages <- Batting %>% filter(yearID %in% c("1999","2000","2001")) %>%
  mutate(pa = AB + BB, singles = (H - X2B - X3B - HR)/pa, bb = BB/pa) %>%
  filter(pa >= 100) %>%
  group_by(playerID) %>%
  summarize(mean_singles = mean(singles), mean_bb = mean(bb)) %>%
  select(playerID, mean_singles, mean_bb)

# Select mean_singles and mean_bb higher than 0.2 as required by the task
averages %>% filter(mean_singles > 0.2) %>% nrow(.)
averages %>% filter(mean_bb > 0.2) %>% nrow(.)
```

The key here is a `summarize` operation that computes averages based on the grouping by playerID (see the `group_by(playerID)` section).

Answer (score 0):

To me the following resulted perfect:

1. How many players had a single rate `mean_singles` of greater than 0.2 per plate appearance over 1999-2001?

```
library(Lahman)

bat_02 <- Batting %>% filter(yearID == 2002) %>%
    mutate(pa = AB + BB, singles = (H - X2B - X3B - HR)/pa, bb = BB/pa) %>%
    filter(pa >= 100) %>%
    select(playerID, singles, bb)

bat_99_01 <- Batting %>% filter(yearID %in% 1999:2001) %>%
    mutate(pa = AB + BB, singles = (H - X2B - X3B - HR)/pa, bb = BB/pa) %>%
    filter(pa >= 100) %>%
    group_by(playerID) %>%
    summarize(mean_singles = mean(singles), mean_bb = mean(bb))
sum(bat_99_01$mean_singles > 0.2)

# The result:
[1] 46
```

2. How many players had a BB rate `mean_bb` of greater than 0.2 per plate appearance over 1999-2001?

```
sum(bat_99_01$mean_bb > 0.2)

# Answer:

[1] 3
```